# Listen SetTimeout to sync loading time

Tags: javascript, css

I created this popup notification on the right bottom corner:

https://jsfiddle.net/gszj4k7y/

```
<div class='personalise-notification' style=''>
  <div class='box'>
    <div style='display: table-row;'>

      <div class='message'>message</div>

    </div>
    <div id="borderBottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It appears with slow animation and after 5 secs it will dissapear due to the SetTimout function:

```
$('.personalise-notification').show().animate({ right: '50'}, 'slow');

setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.personalise-notification').animate({ bottom: '-200'}, 'slow').hide('slow');
}, 5000);
```

I created this absolute div #borderBottom and the goal is to dynamically change the border width when the Timeout will go from 5000 to 0:

```
#borderBottom {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f51c40;
  position: absolute;
  right: 24%;
  left: 0;
}
```

If SetTimeout started and it's 5000 ms, then it the RIGHT property should be 0%... and when the time progress to 0, the RIGHT property will move to 100% as well (or vice versa).

How could I listen the setTimeout and show the borderBottom ~ indicator based on this? Or is there any other way?

The result should eventually behave like this notification: 
http://www.jqueryrain.com/?H40wqtcG

Edit: Wrong URL for jsfiddle - updated now

Comment: did you provided correct jsfiddle link?

Comment: Airful it was wrong - just fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `CSS animation` to perform that as below, It starts `animation` for div placed at bottom at `width` of `80%` to till `0`, you can even set that to `100%`.

```js
$('.personalise-notification').show().animate({
  right: '50'
}, 'slow');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('.personalise-notification').animate({
    bottom: '-200'
  }, 'slow').hide('slow');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.personalise-notification {
  display: one;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: -200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
}

.message {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}

.box {
  display: table;
}

#borderBottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 24%;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f51c40;
  animation: brd 3s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes brd {
  from {
    width: 80%;
  }
  to {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='personalise-notification'>
  <div class='box'>
    <div style='display: table-row;'>

      <div class='message'>message</div>

    </div>
    <div id="borderBottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's easy and perfect solution for this. Thanks so much. Just curious why the animation is faster in the middle and slower on the end? Didn't figure it out

Comment: @Dudis because of the *ease* in CSS `animation: brd 3s ease forwards;` You can have the same effect (or others) in combination with your [`jQuery.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) Could you use them on your message box also like https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/

Comment: Welcome @Dudis :-) and yes that's true it's because of ease which is called animation-timing-function change (ease)  to linear and thus it perform same speed from start to till end. You can even try as suggested by gmo.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#borderBottom').animate({width: 0}, 3000);`

Add this line of code after SetTimeout function.

Animation time will be same as SetTimeout function.

Comment: It does not do anything and it should be about the "right" property and no width?

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` you don't really need `setTimeout` for this.
You can use `delay()` function for the waiting time and a `callback` function for the `#borderBottom` position.

With this, both (notification dialog & borderBottom) will be synchronized in time.

```
// Set waiting time
var waitingTime = 5000;

$('.personalise-notification')
.show()
.animate({
    right: '50'
}, 'slow', function() { // callback to animate borderBottom
    $('#borderBottom').animate({
        right: '100%'
    }, waitingTime);
})
.delay(waitingTime) // like setTimeout
.animate({
    bottom: '-200'
}, 'slow')
.hide('slow');
```

```js
// Set waiting time
var waitingTime = 5000;

$('.personalise-notification')
    .show()
    .animate({
        right: '50'
    }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#borderBottom').animate({
            right: '100%'
        }, waitingTime);
    })
    .delay(waitingTime)
    .animate({
        bottom: '-200'
    }, 'slow')
    .hide('slow');
```

```css
.personalise-notification {
    display: none;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: -200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 350px;
    position: fixed;
}
.message {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}
.box {
    display: table;
}
#borderBottom {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f51c40;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='personalise-notification'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div style='display: table-row;'>
            <div class='message'>message</div>
        </div>
        <div id="borderBottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```